# Implementing a video in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, video

I was wondering how we can implement a video feature in a Spring MVC application. Would I have to use another technology, such as jQuery, or does Spring support a Video feature?

Comment: A video is a resource, just like an image or a CSS file. whether you use Spring MVC or anything else is irelevant. If what you want is streaming, then it's another story. Please clarify what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) supports video streaming (byte-ranges) out of the box.  It supports various backing storage.  Using Spring Content FS (i.e. Spring Content for the Filesystem) you can create yourself a "video store" backed by the filesystem and stream videos that it stores to clients over HTTP.

Create a new Spring Boot project via start.spring.io or via your IDE spring project wizard (Spring Boot 1.5.10 at time of writing).  Add the following Spring Boot/Content dependencies so you end up with these:-

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Content -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then in your Spring Boot Application class, create a VideoStore. Annotate it as a `StoreRestResource.  This does two things; it causes Spring Content to inject an implementation of this interface (for the filesystem), as well as injecting REST endpoints on top of this interface too - saving you from having to write any this yourself:-

```
    @SpringBootApplication 
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {        
           SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);  
        }

        @StoreRestResource(path="videos")   
        public interface VideoStore extends Store<String> {} 
    }
```

By default Spring Content (for the filesystem) will create a store under java.io.tmpdir.  So you will also need to set the SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT environment variable, or system property to set a stable root location for your "store" so when your application/service restarts it can find the video's again.

Copy your video(s) into this "root" location.  Start the application and your video(s) will be streamable from:-

> /videos/some-video.mp4

Spring Content supports other storage too; currently S3, Mongo's GridFS and JPA (i.e. BLOBs).

It can also be used without Spring Boot.  If this alternative is of interest let me know and I can update the answer for you.